# Convert number text field to int (for use in a conditional statement)

Tags: java, android, arrays, textview

So I am very new to Android studio. My problem is relatively simple, convert data from a text field into a integer. The goal of that int is to be used in a conditional statement. However I cannot seem to find an answer that works. This is where my code that i'm having problems with is.

```
    public void saveMatchData (MenuItem item) {                                                           
   //save button in my menu                                                                          
    //creates a toast to notify that it has been pressed                                              

     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save button  pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
      toast.show();                                                                                                                        
   // create an EditText for matchNumberInput                                                         
    EditText matchNumberET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.matchNumberInput);                         
  //assign value of matchNumberET(Edit Text) to match number                                        
    EditText  matchNumber  = (EditText) matchNumberET.getText();                                      
 //attempted to assign to an int                                                                   
   int  matchNumberValue = Integer.parseInt(matchNumber); 
 //                                   error here^^^^^


  //same as abover just tried a different way that i read online                                    
    EditText teamNumberDT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.teamNumberInput);                            
   int  teamNumber = Integer.parseInt(teamNumberDT.getText().toString());             

   int i;                                                                                            
   //i have an array for matchNumber values and teamNumber values                                    
   //they start empty and as of now still are                                                        
   //                                                                                                
    for (i = 0, i <= matchNumberArray.size(), i++);{                                                  
  if (matchNumberValue == matchNumberArray.get(i)){ 
    //        error here^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //I just want to compare the value of i position of the array with the      data from textfield                                  
      //code to add matchNumber if not already there                                            
  }                                                                                             

  //both of these different ways to do this give me errors                                      

   }                                                                                                 
   if (teamNumberArray.get(i) == teamNumber) {    
     //error here^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

     //code to add teamNumber if not already there                                                 
     }                                                                                                 

   Is it a problem with the conversion of the textField to an int or is it the way im using it? Or is it a problem with my array/s?
```

Here is all of my code. Sorry, it's very sloppy.`
             package com.example.garre.frcscouting13;

```
         import android.net.Uri;
         import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
         import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
         import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

         import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
         import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
         import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
         import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
         import android.os.Bundle;
         import android.view.LayoutInflater;
         import android.view.Menu;
         import android.view.MenuItem;
         import android.view.View;
         import android.view.ViewGroup;
         import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
         import android.widget.Button;
         import android.widget.EditText;
         import android.widget.TextView;
         import android.widget.Toast;
         import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
         import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
         import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
         import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
         import java.util.ArrayList;
         import java.util.List;

                   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
                  List<String> matchNumberArray = new ArrayList<String>();

                //String matchNumberArray[] = {};
                ArrayAdapter matchNumberAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>                        (this, R.layout.previous_fragment, matchNumberArray);

                  List<String> teamNumberArray = new ArrayList<String>();


            //  String teamNumberArray[] = {};
              ArrayAdapter teamNumberAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.previous_fragment, teamNumberArray);

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml. @Override

    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.saveMenuItem:

            return true;
        case R.id.ScreenShotMenuItem:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

public void openScreenshotToast(MenuItem item) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screenshot button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

public void saveMatchData (MenuItem item) {
    //save button in my menu
    //creates a toast to notify that it has been pressed

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();


   // create an EditText for matchNumberInput
     EditText matchNumberET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.matchNumberInput);
    //assign value of matchNumberET(Edit Text) to match number
    EditText  matchNumber  = (EditText) matchNumberET.getText();
    //attempted to assign to an int
     int  matchNumberValue = Integer.parseInt(matchNumber);


    //same as abover just tried a different way that i read online
    EditText teamNumberDT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.teamNumberInput);
    int  teamNumber = Integer.parseInt(teamNumberDT.getText().toString());


    int i;
    //i have an array for matchNumber values and teamNumber values
    //they start empty and as of now still are
    //
    for (i = 0, i <= matchNumberArray.size(), i++);{
        if (matchNumberValue == matchNumberArray.get(i)){
            //code to add matchNumber if not already there
        }

        //both of these different ways to do this give me errors

    }
    if (teamNumberArray.get(i) == teamNumber) {
        //code to add teamNumber if not already there
    }

}

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
public Action getIndexApiAction() {
    Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
            .setName("Main Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
            .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
            .build();
    return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
            .setObject(object)
            .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
    client.disconnect();
}


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fieldmap_fragment, container, false);
            return rootView;
        } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.datainput_fragment, container, false);
            return rootView;

        } else {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.previous_fragment, container, false);
            return rootView;

        }
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "FieldMap";
            case 1:
                return "Match Data";
            case 2:
                return "Previous";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: Integer.parseInt() takes a String only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract your `EditText` Value like:

```
EditText matchNumberET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.matchNumberInput);                                      
int  matchNumberValue = Integer.parseInt(matchNumberET.getText().toString());
```

And as seeing your code, I couldn't find your Intention towards the App. Please go through few tutorials as provided on [Google's official site.](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

Comment: The app is for my robotics team. It's to gather data from our compitions and use that to decide who is the best team

Comment: I did that for teamNumber. And then did matchnumber different to show that I've tried some different ways. Niether of them work though.

Answer (score 0):

I did that for teamNumber. And then did matchnumber different to show that I've tried some different ways. Niether of them work though.